# react/next typeScript preact signals Managing global app state error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, preact, preact-signal

Hello i tried to use this preact global app state based on this [documentation](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals#managing-global-app-state) but keep getting error and this my first time using useContext i might be wrong in my config so i appriciate if anybody could tell me what i have done wrong.

this is my globalSignals.ts
src\signals\globalSignal.ts

```
// Library
import { signal } from "signals-react-safe";
import { createContext } from "preact";


// Type
// import type * as user from "@/types/user";

export function createAppState() {
    const session = signal({});
    // const userData = signal(null as user.User | null);
    // const listUser = signal(null as user.ArrUser | null);
    
    return { session }
}

export const MyContext = createContext(createAppState());
```

and this is where i wrap the providers

src\app(dashboard)\layout.tsx

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import { MyContext, createAppState } from "@/signals/globalSignal";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const DashboardLayout = ({ children }: Props) => {

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={createAppState()}>
    <div className="flex flex-col max-h-screen h-screen bg-lighterblue">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="flex flex-auto">
        <Sidebar />
        <div className="ps-10 w-full">
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default DashboardLayout;
```

and this is the error that i got
[image: error]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix Preact and React, they're different libraries and have different internals.

Use `createContext` from React, i.e.:

```
// Library
import { signal } from "signals-react-safe";
-import { createContext } from "preact";
+import { createContext } from 'react';
```